# menu li a:active how can I make it working properly?

Tags: html, css

I am doing a nav bar and I'd like that when a user press on 'showreel' the other two section appear. How can I do that with CSS?

here's my code:

```
<li><a href="showreel.html">showreel</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="showreel.html">director</a></li>
    <li><a href="showreel.html">cinematographer</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: when you say "press" do you mean on mouse click? or maybe mouse hover? Take note that if a user clicks a link (which it seems your "showreel" element is) the page will be redirected.

Comment: what do you mean by "press"? is it "hover" or "click"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mention, you'll probably want to use `:hover` for a hover menu. Note that typical hover menus aren't accessible using only keyboards and extra effort will need to be used to get them working on keyboards. You will need to hook into focus events to do this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JPM7X/)

**CSS**

```
ul li:hover ul,

ul li.forceShow ul
{
    display:block;
}

ul ul {
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('ul a').focusin(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('forceShow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you could show your markup.

Also, for this kind of behaviour, it's really better to use JavaScript instead of CSS. You shouldn't use CSS to change the style of an element depending on another exterior element.

If director and cinematographer are in the same element then maybe a nested selector like this
(I'm assuming your showreel is an anchor and the other one a span)

```
a:active > span {
   display: inline;
}
```

But once again this isn't best practice and you should look into Javascript solutions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, with the new markup that you've provided I don't think you can achieve what you want with just CSS. The reason is that your

```
<a href="showreel.html">showreel</a>
```

`tag is the one who gains the :active pseudo-class but it doesn't contain the other two links. Therefore, the other two links can't be affected by the showreel link, not with only CSS anyways.

If you're willing to use Javascript, the solution is quite simple.